Negative lookup/lookbehind in "declare module" patterns of TypeScript
Currently, the second the declaration shadows the first one.
declare module "*.renderer.pug" {
  const renderer: (templateVariables: unknown) => string;
  export default renderer;
}

declare module "*.pug" {
  const HTML_Template: string;
  export default HTML_Template;
}

According the idea, it is like "if/else": "if file path ends with '.renderer.pug', consider it as function. All other '.pug' module must be considered as string".
Possible to solve this without changing of files naming convention?
Please note that modules loading already has been correctly configured. All that left is explain the above conventions to TypeScript.

This works well

Creating a declaration file next to your tsconfig.json file and including the types you have provided should work as expected.
I have tried it on my machine with the following code:
index.ts:
import shouldBeFunction from "./something.renderer.pug";
import shouldBeString from "./something.pug";
import shouldBeString2 from "./something.extra.pug";

shouldBeFunction();
shouldBeString();
shouldBeString2();

in the following file structure:
$: ls -1
index.ts
package.json
something.extra.pug
something.renderer.pug
something_else.pug
tsconfig.json
types.d.ts

when the typescript compiler is run against this code, the following is the output:
$: tsc --noEmit
index.ts:5:1 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

5 shouldBeFunction();
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  types.d.ts:2:20
    2   const renderer: (templateVariables: unknown) => string;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for 'templateVariables' was not provided.

index.ts:6:1 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

6 shouldBeString();
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

index.ts:7:1 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

7 shouldBeString2();
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors in the same file, starting at: index.ts:5

This indicates that the types are as expected.

Thank you for the answer. I am sorry about I have not clarified this in question, but TypeScript errors which you have posted is exactly what need to be solved. The modules content is been loaded correctly, but models declaration needs to be corrected.

The errors in my answer are just there as i am deliberately misusing the imports. All you need to do is use the imports as expected and there will be no errors. Im not sure what you are asking
